# Adaptive Banner for Android 11 (SDK Version 30) - Kotlin - Deprecated

Tags: kotlin, sdk, deprecated, banner, android-11

Good afternoon. This is my first consultation in the community. I am trying to implement an adaptive banner using the official documentation, but the example has deprecated terms and the help that Android Studio provides is confusing for me.
I was looking for hours in the forum and I did not find an answer to help me.
I would appreciate if you could help me implement an adaptive banner with Kotiln for SDK 30.

```
private lateinit var adView: AdView

private val adSize: AdSize
    get() {
        val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
        val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics)

        val density = outMetrics.density

        var adWidthPixels = frameAnuncio.width.toFloat()
        if (adWidthPixels == 0f) {
            adWidthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat()
        }

        val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()
        return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth)
    }
```

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHV87.jpg)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receta)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    MobileAds.initialize(this) { }

    adView = AdView(this)
    frameAnuncio.addView(adView)
    loadBanner()

}

private fun loadBanner() {
    adView.adUnitId = AD_UNIT_ID

    adView.adSize = adSize

    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build()

    adView.loadAd(adRequest)
}

companion object {
    private val AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"
}
```

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul495.jpg)

The Admob dependency is:
Implementation 'com.google.android.gms: play-services-ads: 19.6.0'

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, you can use `windowManager.currentDisplayMetrics` to get access to window bounds. And `resources.displayMetrics` for access to the density.

```
private val adSize: AdSize
    get() {
        val metrics = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics

        val density = resources.displayMetrics.density

        var adWidthPixels = frameAnuncio.width.toFloat()
        if (adWidthPixels == 0f) {
            adWidthPixels = metrics.bounds.width().toFloat()
        }

        val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()
        return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth)
    }
```

The new way of adding a test device is explained in the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#add_your_test_device_programmatically).

Comment: In `val density = metrics.density` the ***density*** reference is not recognized. In `adWidthPixels = metrics.widthPixels.toFloat()` the ***widthPixels*** is not recognized and `val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()` the division is not recognized either.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this it gives same value to the original code snippet from the documentation

```
private AdSize getAdSize() {

    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    float widthPixels = getScreenWidth();
    float density = outMetrics.density;

    int adWidth = (int) (widthPixels / density);

    return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth);

}

public int getScreenWidth() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        WindowMetrics windowMetrics = getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics();
        Insets insets = windowMetrics.getWindowInsets()
                .getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars());
        return windowMetrics.getBounds().width() - insets.left - insets.right;
    } else {
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return outMetrics.widthPixels;
    }
}
```